# Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

IDE shows error when I write this code.

I have a component that calls service in ngOnInit to get the data. Service calls the other service to get some data and use it to get data then returns it.

component:

```
ngOnInit() {
    const token = "abc";
    this.service.getContactPersons(token).subscribe(
      persons => this.contactPersons = persons
    );

  }
```

service:

```
getContactPersons(token: string): Observable<ContactPerson[]> {
return this.tokenService.getParameters(token).pipe(
      switchMap((data: Params) => {
        return this.http.get<Properties>(
          this.baseUrl + `/abc/${data.param1}/properties/${data.param2}`
        );
      })
    ).subscribe((data: Properties) => data.contactPersons);
}
```

I've got this error: "Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 6 more."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`subscribe` is not an rxjs equivalent of `then`. Specifically, with promises you can do `somePromise.then(doSomething).then(doSomethingElse)`, but you can't `someRxjsStream$.subscribe(doSomething).subscribe(doSomethingElse)`. If you want to transform the data stream, you should use one of several available rxjs operators, and in your case it's `map`:

```
getContactPersons(token: string): Observable<ContactPerson[]> {
    return this.tokenService.getParameters(token).pipe(
        switchMap((data: Params) => this.http.get<Properties>(
            `${this.baseUrl}/abc/${data.param1}/properties/${data.param2}`)),
        map((data: Properties) => data.contactPersons));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

your function `getContactPersons` returns a subscriptions as it is now.
just delete the `.subscribe((data: Properties) => data.contactPersons);` part of your function and it should do the trick.

Since your are going to return an Observable you should always try to just pass along the observable itself or perform Operations on it within a `pipe()` and only subscribe to it once, because multiple Subscription can get out of hand and result in memory leak and therefore performance loss for your users.

Comment: When I deleted subscribe I've got "Type 'Observable<Properties>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<ContactPerson[]>'."

Comment: Yes indead i forgot that point. See mbojko's answer for a solution